# How to write a doIf block in Gatling with 2 conditions

Tags: java, scala, session, conditional-statements, gatling

I want to write a doIf block which checks if either "studentPersonalRefId" OR "teacherAssignmentRefId" are null. If so, output a message that something is null. Otherwise, continue with the "getCanvasAssignments" requests:

```
.doIfEqualsOrElse((session -> String.valueOf(session.getString("studentPersonalRefId")),"null") || ( session -> String.valueOf(session.getString("teacherAssignmentRefId")),"null").then(
    exec(session -> {
        log.info("studentPersonalRefId or teacherAssingnmentRefId is null");
        log.info("studentPersonalRefId = " + session.getString("studentPersonalRefId") + " teacherAssignmentRefId = " + session.getString("teacherAssignmentRefId"));
        return session;
    })
}).orElse(
    //Fetch the assignment which takes refId as a param, if the refId exists
            exec(getCanvasAssignments);

)
```

Is something similar to this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
.doIfOrElse(session -> 
  !session.contains("studentPersonalRefId") || 
  !session.contains("teacherAssignmentRefId")
).then(
```

Comment: I used that but now get the following errors even though my JDK is configured on Intellij:

Cannot resolve method 'doIfEqualsOrElse(<lambda expression>)'
Cannot resolve method 'contains(String)'

Comment: Fixed: doIfEqualsOrElse => doIfOrElse

Comment: Ah I didn't see the change there. Thank you very much.